# Measuring peak memory usage: equivalent of /usr/bin/time -v including child/forked processes

Tags: linux, memory, python, forking

I have been making use of the /usr/bin/time -v  construct for a while now in order to determine the peak RAM usage of programs that I create.

Lately I have been making some python programs that make use of `multiprocessing` which basically makes a fork of the parent process. The RAM usage of these forked processes is seemingly not captured by /usr/bin/time.

Is there a similar tool to measure peak RAM usage, but combined over all forked processes / child processes of the parent?

Comment: Have the same question for `child_process.fork` in nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [this experimental script](https://heptapod.host/saajns/procpath/-/snippets/13) around this use case, process tree-aware version of GNU time, based on [Procpath](https://pypi.org/project/Procpath/) -- a tool for analysing Linux process trees that I maintain. Rough around edges, but good enough to illustrate the idea -- record the target process tree metrics that procfs
provides, then run queries with `sqlite3` against the recorded database.

```
$ ./time-pp.sh stress -t 45 -c 2 -m 1
2023-05-29 23:12:03 INFO    procpath №1: stress: info: [451026] dispatching hogs: 2 cpu, 0 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd
2023-05-29 23:12:48 INFO    procpath №1: stress: info: [451026] successful run completed in 45s
tracked 44.84s
user    94.94s
sys 39.54s

CPU timeline    ▇███████████████████████████████████████
CPU min-max 298.71% - 331.70%

RSS timeline    ███████▇▇███▇█▇▇█▂▇▇▇██▇█▇████▇██▇█▄▇█▇█
RSS min-max 1.50MiB - 257.25MiB
```

`procpath` and `pysparklines` commands are prerequisite. Can be installed like
this:

```
$ pipx install procpath
$ pipx install pysparklines
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU time (/usr/bin/time) uses wait4 to get rusage of the parent process and child processes as long as the parent process waits for the child processes to complete:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955309/does-gnu-time-memory-output-account-for-child-processes-too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind can measure memory usage of Python programs, I have never used it on multi-threading yet. But this link seems to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131803/why-does-an-object-allocation-local-to-a-python-subprocess-increase-heap-size-fo and Callgrind seems to be a functionality designed for this https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html